# printf format question

Tags: perl, format, printf

This script outputs "abc". How could I change the FORMAT part of printf to get "123" as output?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;


my $str = 'abc123';

printf "%3.3s\n", $str;

# abc
```

Comment: Why are you averse to slicing the string?

Comment: I had a sudden inspiration to try it with printf to have one more option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "truncate left" with `printf`'s [format strings](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

You will need to strip the part you want by using either a regex or [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html), depending on what the exact logic is that you apply to get "123" out of that string.

```
print substr($str, 3, 3) . "\n"; # Get 3 scharacters from char #4
```

or

```
print substr($str, -3) . "\n"; # Get last 3 chars
```

or

```
$str =~ /(\d+)/; # Get the first digits-only substring
print "$1\n";
```